# Не понимаю как сделать второй пункт в задании(С#)

Tags: c#

Ввести две отдельные строки, содержащие по меньшей мере по 4 слова.
Выполнить следующие действия:

- 1.Поменять местами последние слова в двух строчках
- 2.Удалить из первой половины первой строки все слова которые совпадают с последним словом второй строки
- 3.Дополнить вторую строчку до 40 символов пробелами в конце строке
- 4.Вывести полученные строки на экран

Если можете помогите мне **написать второй пункт**(изучать с# начал недавно + практики мало, поэтому, можно по-простому объяснить)

***Вот какой код на данный момент***

```
     using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //1
            Console.Write("Введите 1 строчку  ");
            string a1 = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Введите 2 строчку  ");
            string b1 = Console.ReadLine();

            string notlword1 = a1.Remove(a1.LastIndexOf(' '));
            string notlword2 = b1.Remove(b1.LastIndexOf(' '));
            string lword1 = a1.Remove(0, a1.LastIndexOf(' '));
            string lword2 = b1.Remove(0, b1.LastIndexOf(' '));
            string c = notlword1 + lword2;
            string d = notlword2 + lword1;
            //2


            //3
            string f = b1.PadRight(40);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("первая строка с последним словом второй  " + c);
            Console.WriteLine("вторая строка с последним словом второй  " + d);
            Console.WriteLine(f + " ");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: `string.Split()` вас спасет

Comment: Если рассматривать строки не как строки, как массив строк, то задача становится проще. С помощью split() как сказал @aepot, делим строку по правилам на отдельные элементы, а дальше дело за малым. Если вас не ограничивают в оптимальности, то пишите цикл, который перебирает первый цикл до передины, и в нём ещё цикл поторый перебирает второй массив после середины.

Comment: @SergeySemkin `как массив строк` как массив слов

Comment: Забыл, есть такая штука как string.builder. Преобразовал строку в массив, похимичил с массивом и опять в строку преобразовал и вернул

Comment: @aepot извиняюсь за ошибку

Comment: @SergeySemkin  Мне преподаватель сказал чтобы без массивов делал задание,а как тогда мне решить данный вопрос?